# Google Sheets - Multiple if statements with and function

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to build a check in/ check out tracker for my team using google forms and google sheets. The idea is that once Someone submits their response through google form, it comes to google sheet. There I would match the data against my existing staff list and determine who checked in and who has not. I have google forms part down but I am struggling with matching data with the existing staff list.

This is how I set that up and that is how my dataset and formula look like.

Dataset in Original tab (Check In / Check Out tab)

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sep 16, 2021 08:05 AM | ABC@XYZ.com | Check In |
| Sep 16, 2021 09:01 AM | DFG@XYZ.com | Check In |
| Sep 16, 2021 04:15 PM | ABC@XYZ.com | Check Out |

desired outcome and Formula in a New tab

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| ABC@XYZ.com | Formula |
| DFG@XYZ.com | Formula |

*A1 = email address

=If(AND('Check In / Check Out'!B:B = A1, 'Check In / Check Out'!D:D = Today(),'Check In / Check Out'!C:C = "Check in"), "Checked in",
if(AND('Check In / Check Out'!B:B = A1, 'Check In / Check Out'!D:D = Today(),'Check In / Check Out'!C:C = "Check Out"),"Checked out", "Not Checked in"))

I tried slightly different variations of the above formula but no success. Can anyone please suggest how can I get the desired outcome? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data table has headers in row 1 and the data starts on row 2, use `query()` with a `pivot` clause to get the last check in and check out on the current date like this:

```
=query( 
  'Check In / Check Out'!A1:C, 
  "select B, max(A) 
   where toDate(A) = date " & text(today(), "'yyyy-mm-dd'") & " 
   group by B 
   pivot C", 
  1 
)
```

The results roughly match your expected result table structure. Note that the formula will *not* list staff that have failed to check in and also failed to check out on the current date.

To place these results side-by-side with a static list of names in another tab, use `vlookup()`.

Comment: Hi @Doubleunary,

Thank you for your solution! That worked like magic! The only thing I want to change is to have a static list of email addresses in the new tab and automatically update check in/check out time if that person put their answer through the google form and leave corresponding cell empty if that person has not checked in/Checked off through google form.  This way I can see who has not logged in yet.  
Hope this make sense. Once again thank you very much. really appreciate it!

Comment: Your place the results from the query side-by-side with a static list of names in another tab with a `vlookup()` formula in that other tab. Cannot provide more detailed advice because you have not shared a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much again!